# MacOS: mounting password-protected sparsebundle doesn't ask for password

Tags: macos, security, mount, sparsebundle

I have an encrypted, password-protected sparsebundle that I occasionally mount and unmount from the terminal. I want the system to ask for the password every time I mount it, but for some reason it keeps remembering.

This is how I mount it: `hdiutil attach ~/path/to/my/bundle -mountpoint ~/my/mountpoint`

These are some of the ways I've tried to unmount it:

```
hdiutil detach -force ~/path/to/my/bundle
hdiutil detach -force /Users/me/path/to/my/bundle
hdiutil eject -force ~/path/to/my/bundle
diskutil eject ~/path/to/my/bundle
diskutil unmount force ~/path/to/my/bundle
```

(I've read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230572/encrypted-sparsebundle-password-appears-to-be-cached) that `hdiutil unmount` is not sufficient to make the system forget the password.)

However, whatever I try, the system "helpfully" remembers the password each time.

Only when I use the eject button in Finder, does the system forget the password.

Also, there is no entry in my keychain that suggest the password has been cached. (At least, I can't find it. There are none with kind `disk image password`.)

I've even created a new sparsebundle, with a new name and a different password, but the problem persists.

What am I missing here? How can I make sure the sytem **always** asks for the password, each time I mount the sparsebundle?

Comment: In this [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5055489) the following procedure was suggested: "I had to first use `unmount force` option, then open the volume again in the script, then eject it. And that worked."

Comment: Tried it, but sadly doesn't work for me.

Comment: Using detach, then closing the terminal session. Will opening a new terminal session still allow you to mount without password?

Comment: Another case of Apple saving you from yourself. Ease of use is more important than security.

Comment: @Elmo Nope. Only the eject button in finder seems to work reliably so far. And rebooting the system.

Comment: What version are you running?  On El Capitan, "hdiutil eject ~/my/mountpoint" (note not "~/path/to/my/bundle" as in the question) results on password prompt on all subsequent "hdiutil attach ~/Documents/Test.sparsebundle -mountpoint ~/my/mountpoint"

Comment: @lx07 I'm running Mojave.

Comment: @lx07 I just gave it another shot with the exact same commands that you mention, but still no dice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels kind of sad, but in the end I managed to find a way to do it using AppleScript:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject "<name>"'
```

The `<name>` should match the name in Finder's sidebar.